# Passing Variables Through URL Not Working In Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, url

So I am trying to pass variables into Javascript through a websites URL. I have set this website up:

```
https://teamhaxor.000webhostapp.com/variabletest.html?test=contents
```

What this is is a file called "variabletest.html" and I am trying to pass the variable "test" with a value of "contents" into it. The code of this file is here:

```
<script>

alert(test)

</script>
```

The debug output says that the variable "test" is not defined. I don't understand why? Is it my web host not supporting variable passing?

Note: I have also tried putting quotes around the string.

Comment: You've to catch the test variable from Query String using any server side scripting language.

Comment: This questions is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I was so blind to that post.